# Function wont eager compile

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, v8

I recently tried to eager compile my javascript function from the guide shown in the link-https://v8.dev/blog/code-caching-for-devs

But even after enclosing the function in IIFE heuristics as said above, the [V8 System analyzer shows its lazy compiled, and unoptimized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ7YI.png). It is not showing under the eager compile section. The creation time however shifted to the front, but there is no noticeable performance change. Does this mean that eager compile functions don't perform faster? Then what exactly is the advantage of a eager compile function?

(pls note, the below function is created for learning purposes. I use this to learn about eager compiling js functions):
script.js:

```
const a = 1000;
const b = 2000;

const add = function(a,b) {
    var sampleObject2={
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        age: 70,
        eyeColor: "blue"
      };
    var c=a**b;
    var d=b**c;
    c=c+21;
    d=d+c;
    d=d**sampleObject2.age;
    console.log(c**d);
    return c**d;
};
window.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  var start=performance.now()
  add(a,b);
  var end=performance.now()
  console.log(end-start);
},false);
```

Comment: @Bravo I am actually just learning about eager compile functions. So its just a dummy function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> the V8 System analyzer shows its lazy compiled

That's not what I'm seeing: with the code as written in your question, i.e. `const add = function(a, b) { ... };`, the System Analyzer says `type: LazyCompile~`.
When I add the parentheses that (currently!) get interpreted as an eager-compilation hint, i.e. `const add = (function(a, b) = { ... });`, that changes to `type: Function~` (as in your screenshot; so I guess you did actually add the parentheses before running the test that produced that screenshot).

> and unoptimized

That is expected. Optimization has nothing to do with lazy compilation. There is no way to optimize a function right away, because attempting that would make no sense: the optimizer can't do anything useful if it doesn't have type feedback to work with, which can only be collected during unoptimized execution.

> Does this mean that eager compile functions don't perform faster?

Correct, the function's own performance doesn't change at all.

> Then what exactly is the advantage of a eager compile function?

Preparing a function for later lazy compilation has a small cost. In case the function will be needed soon, compiling it right away avoids this cost. In fact, I do see a tiny difference in the times that your test reports; although I haven't verified that this difference is actually due to eager vs. lazy compilation, it may well be caused by something else.

If eager-compiling everything was a good idea, then engines would do it -- that'd be much easier. In reality, lazy-compiling is almost always worth the tiny amount of extra work it creates, because it makes startup/pageload faster, and can avoid quite a bit of memory consumption when there are unused functions, e.g. in your included libraries. So JavaScript engines accept a lot of internal complexity to make lazy compilation possible. I wouldn't recommend attempting to side-step that.

(For completeness: a couple of years ago V8's implementation of lazy compilation was not as optimized as it is today, and manually hinting eager compilation could achieve more significant improvements, especially for deeply nested functions. But these times are gone! And now it's just one more example that illustrates that in general you shouldn't go to great lengths to adapt your code to what engines are *currently* doing well or not-so-well.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Honestly, learning about the [V8 tools](https://v8.github.io/tools/head/) is quite hard, since there is very little information regarding it. Can you also suggest any good resources for both the V8 tools and about V8 itself? the jargon used in the V8 tools (especially indicium) is a little confusing..

Comment: @AshwinKumar Yeah, the tools aren't really targeted at public consumption, they're mostly written by those who use them (who are hence already deeply familiar with the topic in question). For learning about V8 as a whole, v8.dev/blog (which you already found) is probably the largest collection of material.